# Difference between tf.data.Dataset.map() and tf.data.Dataset.apply()

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

With the recent upgrade to version 1.4, Tensorflow included `tf.data` in the library core.
One "major new feature" described in the [version 1.4 release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/RELEASE.md) is [`tf.data.Dataset.apply()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#apply), which is a "method for
applying custom transformation functions". How is this different from the already existing [`tf.data.Dataset.map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map)?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The difference is that `map` will execute one function on every element of the `Dataset` separately, whereas `apply` will execute one function on the whole `Dataset` at once (such as [`group_by_window`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/group_by_window) given as example in the documentation).

The argument of `apply` is a function that takes a `Dataset` and returns a `Dataset` when the argument of `map` is a function that takes one element and returns one transformed element.

Comment: ...I was wondering where was the documentation for the new functions to use with `apply`. And now I see that the functions are in tf.**contrib**.data, while the Dataset API was moved to tf.data, which is where I was searching for.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand the difference in practical terms. `map` is used to transform the values in a dataset, while `apply` operates "on" the dataset itself... so `apply` could also replace `map`?

Comment: `apply` is used when you need to consider several elements at once. For example, if you want to create a dataset with averages of five consecutive elements in your dataset, then you couldn't do that with `map`

Comment: I see! Ok, that now makes sense. So, if I got it correctly, `apply` can replace entirely `map` (because if it has access to all items, it can also have access to them one at a time like `map`), but writing functions for `apply` is not as straightforward as writing functions that operate on the values themselves, so we get to keep `map` for practical reasons.
Does that make sense?

Comment: That's how I understand it, yes. If you wanted to replace `map` with an `apply` call, then your function inside `apply` would have to do the equivalent of a `map` anyway.

Answer (score 21):

[Sunreef's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47096355/3574081) is absolutely correct. You might still be wondering *why* we introduced [`Dataset.apply()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#apply), and I thought I'd offer some background.

The `tf.data` API has a set of **core** transformations—like `Dataset.map()` and `Dataset.filter()`—that are generally useful across a wide range of datasets, unlikely to change, and implemented as methods on the `tf.data.Dataset` object. In particular, they are subject to the same [backwards compatibility guarantees](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/version_compat) as other core APIs in TensorFlow.

However, the core approach is a bit restrictive. We also want the freedom to experiment with new transformations before adding them to the core, and to allow other library developers to create their own reusable transformations. Therefore, in TensorFlow 1.4 we split out a set of **custom** transformations that live in `tf.contrib.data`. The custom transformations include some that have very specific functionality (like [`tf.contrib.data.sloppy_interleave()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/sloppy_interleave)), and some where the API is still in flux (like [`tf.contrib.data.group_by_window()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/group_by_window)). Originally we implemented these custom transformations as functions from `Dataset` to `Dataset`, which had an unfortunate effect on the syntactic flow of a pipeline. For example:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(...).map(...)

# Method chaining breaks when we apply a custom transformation.
dataset = custom_transformation(dataset, x, y, z)

dataset = dataset.shuffle(...).repeat(...).batch(...)
```

Since this seemed to be a common pattern, we added `Dataset.apply()` as a way to chain core and custom transformations in a single pipeline:

```
dataset = (tf.data.TFRecordDataset(...)
           .map(...)
           .apply(custom_transformation(x, y, z))
           .shuffle(...)
           .repeat(...)
           .batch(...))
```

It's a minor feature in the grand scheme of things, but hopefully it helps to make `tf.data` programs easier to read, and the library easier to extend.

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I hoped to understand, and the piece I was missing to fully grasp the new interface. I'll leave @Sunreef's answer marked as "the" answer, but in truth the two answers complement each other.

Comment: @mrry how are map and apply are executed, are their executed on the batch size everytime you can next element of the iterator or are applied to the whole dataset  once the graph has been initialized? the reason i am asking is because loading a dataset such as imagenet might take much longer if applied on the every batch that once for all on the whole dataset

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan Most transformations in `tf.data` are stateless and streaming, which means that they can return results immediately and consume little memory when dealing with large datasets that might not fit in memory. This means that, if you have a `Dataset.repeat()` following those transformations, they will execute on each pass through the data. If you want to avoid this, add a `Dataset.cache()` after the transformations that you want to perform once.

Comment: @mrry could you provide a "hello world implementation" of `custom_transformation`?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I just wanted to point out that you can actually use map to apply to multiple elements in a dataset contrary to @sunreef's comments on his own post.

According to the documentation, map takes as an argument

> map_func: A function mapping a nested structure of tensors (having
>   shapes and types defined by self.output_shapes and self.output_types)
>   to another nested structure of tensors.

the output_shapes are defined by the dataset and can be modified by using api functions like batch. So, for example, you can do a batch normalization using only dataset.batch and .map with:

```
dataset = dataset ...
dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset.map(normalize_fn)
```

It seems like the primary utility of `apply()` is when you really want to do a transformation across the entire dataset.

Comment: Your use-case can indeed be built with a combination of batch and map, but map is still operating on the single values of the dataset it's called on (which in this case are of course batches). Apply is more general, because it allows, for example, to have variable-length batches, reordering, grouping, etc. @Sunreef's example of group_by_window cannot be reproduced with map() (note that this isn't a transformation that needs to be processed on the whole dataset, since windows could be built incrementally)

Comment: I agree -- again this was more of a comment directed at people new to datasetAPI who might not be familiar with the way "element" is actually a dynamic concept depending on how you define the dataset.  Its intuitive once you get it, but took me a second.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, the arguement of `transformation_func` of `apply()` is `Dataset`; the arguement of `map_func` of `map()` is `element`